# weight with minimum spanning tree and connected graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics

prove show that if a weighted, connected graph has one edge of minimum weight, then this edge must be included in every minimum spanning tree.

how to prove weight with minimum spanning tree. and I am also confusing what is the weighted, is it "every graph has real value on their edges then then they are weighted"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a weighted graph is a graph for which every edge has a (usually positive) real number attached to it.  The weight of the tree is just the sum of the numbers on the edges of the tree.

To show your question, suppose you have a tree that does not contain the minimal edge.  What happens if we add the minimal edge?  It's not a tree anymore, so it contains a cycle.  The cycle must involve this minimal edge because it wasn't there before.  Now if we remove any other edge in this cycle, which is not minimal since the minimal edge is unique, the graph remains connected and we again have a tree.

But the weight of the tree is lower, so if we started with a minimal spanning tree, we could never have added this minimal edge, meaning that it was already attached.  So we're done.